# Google Calendar API, log on another than logged user

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm using Google Calendar API to read user events. At first start, Google displays a consent screen to logged user. Can it be another user? I want to ask for permission user that is logged in my program, not the one that is logged to Chrome browser. Can I set user the consent will show to? Or somehow logout logged user?

```
//code
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3;
using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CalendarQuickstart
{
    class Program
    {
        // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
        // at ~/.credentials/calendar-dotnet-quickstart.json
        static string[] Scopes = { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar };
        static string ApplicationName = "Google Calendar API .NET Quickstart";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UserCredential credential;

            using (var stream =
                new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                    System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/calendar-dotnet-quickstart.json");

                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
            }

            // Create Google Calendar API service.
            var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });

            // Define parameters of request.
            EventsResource.ListRequest request = service.Events.List("primary");
            request.TimeMin = DateTime.Now;
            request.ShowDeleted = false;
            request.SingleEvents = true;
            request.MaxResults = 10;
            request.OrderBy = EventsResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.StartTime;

            // List events.
            Events events = request.Execute();
            Console.WriteLine("Upcoming events:");
            if (events.Items != null && events.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var eventItem in events.Items)
                {
                    string when = eventItem.Start.DateTime.ToString();
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(when))
                    {
                        when = eventItem.Start.Date;
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", eventItem.Summary, when);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No upcoming events found.");
            }
            Console.Read();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "user",  tells FileDataStore which user credentials to load.  If you hard code it like that its always going to be the same user you are loading.  Which is probably a really bad idea.

Comment: I'm changing "user" to "something@gmail.com" but browser is trying to get permission from last logged user. In every example I see user set to "user" so I still don't know how to ask for permission another user. What should I pass in the user string?

Comment: The browser will try and get permissions of who ever is logged into the browser.  If the user wants to log into a different account then they can choose to do that you cant force them to have a different user logged in. This might help you understand what the client library is doing http://www.daimto.com/google-net-filedatastore-demystified/

Comment: So the only thing I can do is to change user string and hope that new user will see that he should log out and log in on his account before giving permission? Isn't there at least some option to log out currently logged user?

Comment: I am unsure how that would happen unless you are running your application on a machine that has multiple users.  But yes its up to you to change that for different users.   Web applications set a cookie in the users browser that identifies the user.   Then they know who to load for if the browser doesn't have said cookie then the user is prompted to login again.    Installed applications normally only have one user so its not an issue.

Comment: If a user has serval accounts its going to be up to them to switch between the accounts.  As an application developer you will be unable to guess which account they want to use.

Comment: I know which account user want to use because user pass his email to the  application- I must use this exact account. Perfect solution for me was in previous Google Calendar Api version- user pass his email and password to the application and application uses this account, plain and simple.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113485/discussion-between-daimto-and-therko).